# change colour for parameters on powershell linux

Tags: linux, powershell, console, powershell-core

[image: pwsh parameter colour]

can you see the `-Uri` Parameter? this is very hard to read on linux.

is there a way to change the colour?

Comment: This is good and useful information, but probably would be more appropriate on [su] or [unix.se], as the issue is not "[unique to software development](/help/on-topic)". As always, prior to posting on another site, please read the on-topic page for whichever site on which you are thinking of posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hemant [answered my question on twitter](https://twitter.com/HemanMahawar/status/1061010537398493184). You can see the colour settings with the Cmdlet `Get-PSReadLineOption`. To edit the property `ParameterColor` I ran `Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{"Parameter"=[ConsoleColor]::Gray}`.

Comment: Yes.. Looking at `Get-Help -Name Set-PSReadLineOption` would tell you this.

Comment: also useful: `Get-Help -Name Set-PSReadLineOption -examples`